# shell script if condition too many arguments

Tags: shell, if-statement, compare

/root/mp3/ path contains below file.
i want to move the file contain letter "in" to other folder

```
  2017-02-10-12-11-05-in.talaw
  2017-02-10-12-11-05-out.talaw
  2017-02-10-12-12-05-in.alaw
  2017-02-10-12-12-05-out.alaw


  $FILES=/root/mp3/*
  for f in "$FILES"
  do
   ef=$(ls $f | awk -F"." '{print $1}' | awk -F "-" '{print $NF}')
  #to check in for a file
   if [ $ef = "in" ]
  #if file contian "in" letter then move to other folder )
    then 
    mv /FILES /sotrage 
    fi
  done
```

getting error  too many arguments at if [ $ef = "in" ]
if i  tried with if [ "$ef" == "in" ] i am not getting current output

```
  i am using if [ $ef = "in" ]  to compare if file contains "in"
```

then only it should move files conatians in to other folder

Comment: Is there a way to convert these .talaw files to mp3/wav? I wish to feed these calls to a speech-to-text converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really what you want to do is `mv -t /destination /root/mp3/*-in.*`

---

You are having problems due to the you're storing the pattern in a variable:

```
$FILES=/root/mp3/*
for f in "$FILES"; do
```

At this point, `$f` contains the literal string `"/root/mp3/*"` -- the pattern has not been expanded yet because of the quotes around `"$FILES"`

Then, you do this

```
  ef=$(ls $f | awk -F"." '{print $1}' | awk -F "-" '{print $NF}')
```

`$f` is unquoted, so the shell expands the pattern and `ls` finally sees the list of all the files. You're passing `awk` several lines of text. `$ef` will contain newlines. Try `echo "$ef"` at this point.

Comment: thanks after removing $ before FILES i am getting correct output.Before moving the file i will mix with other file so i am using if

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your compete requirement as your question is only related to if condition try changing the condition to `[ $ef == "in" ]` OR `[[ $ef == "in" ]]` Because single = means it will work as a assignment operator not as a condition. Kindly give it a try and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: my requirement is only files name which contains "in" letter should move to other folder tried this [ $ef == "in" ] but it not able to validate in letter